# realtime data communication between two c++ executeables one windows and other in virtual machine ubuntu

Tags: c++, windows, ubuntu, rpc, ros

I am running ros to control a robot using ubuntu. But the drivers are available for windows only.
I have setup a virtual machine where the robot controller is built on roscpp

I want pass these values generated using ros to a cpp in windows.
it should be realtime. data should be flowing back and forth.
data: float32 array dimension is 7

Please help me with an example.

Comment: use sockets. Udp is good for realtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the best ways to pass real-time data between two machines is UDP sockets.

You can find some good examples for windows at [MSDN UDP Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms881658.aspx)

One for linux at [Linux UDP Example](http://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~pxk/417/notes/sockets/udp.html)

Comment: In practice, if the bandwidth is not very high (which is probable in robotics, if speaking of driving commands, not video), TCP sockets would be good enough and simpler to code.

Comment: Agree'd TCP would definitely work here as well. I find UDP simpler to code just cause of all the extra protocol you need to consider for TCP though, but in general case that wouldn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

I used ROS on windows and ubuntu.
TCP/IP communication - doesn't matter if the ubuntu machine is on virtual machine. Set the network adapter to Host Only.

ROS Master on Windows. Start executable on Ubuntu and it should post values in the ROS Master which is running on windows.
The executable on Windows can subscribe to those messages.